# Does inversion occur after comma?

Tags: grammar, commas, inversion

Which of the following is correct?

> - Only after he came home did I go to bed.
> - Only after he came home, I went to bed.

Is the second clause correct?

Or is inversion compulsory in that case too?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**only after I came home** is a negative adverb phrase. You are right that it is necessary to invert the subject and the auxiliary verb after a negative adverb: you can read more about that [here](https://www.grammaring.com/only-after-only-if-only-in-this-way-etc-not-until).

Adverbs of frequency can be separated from the sentence by a comma:

> Usually, I have lunch at the cafe on the corner.

Negative adverbs cannot separated from the sentence by a comma- for example

> Never, have I seen such a mess. - **wrong**

Your second sentence is therefore incorrect.