# Whether to use comma in Inversion

Tags: grammar, inversion

We usually say : "**John could** earn enough money only in this way" without Inversion.
We say : "Only in this way **could John** earn enough money" with Inversion.

But my question is : Can I (or should I) put a comma after the phrase "Only in this way" to avoid using Inversion ?
Can we say : "Only in this way, **John could** earn enough money" without Inversion ?

Comment: Ask yourself whether the start of the sentence before the comma and the end of the  sentence after the comma, make sense without the intermediate phrase: **Say...John could earn enough money.** If it doesn't make sense, you can't.

Comment: @Mohammed Salim: Was the word "Say" (in your last sentence) included by accident?

Comment: Whether to use comma in Inversion
We usually say  : "John could earn enough money only in this way" without Inversion. 
We say  : "Only in this way could John earn enough money" with Inversion.

But my question is  : Can I (or should I) put a comma after the phrase "Only in this way" to avoid using Inversion ?
Can we say : "Only in this way, John could earn enough money" without Inversion ?

Comment: Idiomatically, we have a strong tendency to place adverbial ***only*** between the auxiliary and the main verb in such context: *John **could only earn** enough money **in this way***. Combining ***only*** with the *other* adverbial element and "fronting" it (along with "inversion" of auxiliary verb + subject) is an *extremely* "literary" construction that would almost never occur in normal conversational contexts: ***Only in this way could John earn** enough money*. I can't see any arrangement that would justify a comma (or pause in speech), though.

Comment: I have edited your Post [ https://ell.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/20400 ] which may be what you are actually asking for. If that is correct , then I request you to approve it. @MohammedSalim

Comment: I have approved

Answer (score 1):

**(A)** It is a Negative Sense to use "Only" , Eg Compare these two or three Cases :

"John can earn enough money in this way"
"John can earn enough money **only** in this way"
"John can earn enough money in whichever way"

The "Only* is used when no other way was Possible , hence it is restricting the Possibilities (**In this way & no other way**) & It may be considered Negative in Sense.

With that thinking , when inverting the Clauses , the Subject-verb Inversion is required.
"**John could** earn enough money only in this way"
"Only in this way [,] **could John** earn enough money"

**(B)** In case it was not Negative Sense , then Inverting the clauses does not require the Subject-verb Inversion.

"**John could** earn enough money in this way"
"In this way [,] **John could** earn enough money"

The Comma is not necessary , but looks nicer with that.

**(C)** There are Cases where even with inversion of clauses , the Subject-verb inversion is not used.

[Example](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that_way_madness_lies) :
"that way madness lies"
"that way lies madness"

References to Check :
https://www.grammaring.com/only-after-only-if-only-in-this-way-etc-not-until
[Does inversion occur after comma?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216729/does-inversion-occur-after-comma)
["Only if" + comma + inversion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147200/only-if-comma-inversion)